# .htaccess URL rewrite to multi-parameter item

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

I just spent the last 10 hours of my life on this & am running in circles, so was hoping someone may be able to help me.

I want a specific URL to load like this:

> http://example.com/f/2011/image.png?attribute=small

When a URL in a format such as this hits, I'd like to rewrite it to hit the server as:

> http://example.com/generate.php?f=2011/image.png&attribute=small

Based on above, my question is two-fold:

1. How can I rewrite the URL in htaccess to meet my requirements above?
2. If the original URL didn't have the attribute query string parameter, how can I ensure attribute will be false/blank/etc when it hits the server via htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
# If it's not an existing file...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# ...and it's not an existing directory...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# ...and it starts with "f/" then rewrite it to generate.php
RewriteRule ^f/(.*)$ generate.php?f=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The two `RewriteCond` can be omitted. More information:

[RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

[QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/image.png?attribute=small$ generate.php?f=$2/image.png&attribute=small&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that have more chances to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If it's not an existing file...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# ...and it's not an existing directory...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# ...and it starts with "f/" then rewrite it to generate.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/image\.png$ /generate.php?f=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Please tell me if it works